# Class inheritance PHP [private vs protected and public]

Tags: php

**Example code 1:**

```
<?php
class People
{
    private function status() {return __METHOD__;}
    public function Sleep(){
        echo $this->status().'<br />';
    }
}
class Programmer extends People
{
    private function status() {return __METHOD__;}
}
$obj = new Programmer();
$obj->Sleep();
?>
```

**Printed:**`People::status`

**Example code 2:**

```
<?php
class People
{
    protected function status() {return __METHOD__;}
    public function Sleep(){
        echo $this->status().'<br />';
    }
}
class Programmer extends People
{
    protected function status() {return __METHOD__;}
}
$obj = new Programmer();
$obj->Sleep();
?>
```

**Printed:**`Programmer::status`

All different in modifier methods private and protected.

Why in first case i get `People::status`? Why i did not get `Programmer::status`.

Explain me please, i don't understand this moment.

Comment: Because `People` don't have access to `Programmer` private methods.

Comment: why? i inherit People class - its mean i have `sleep()`in Programmer class

Comment: Only protected and public methods/variables can an extending class inherit.

Comment: I talk about `status()`

Comment: i already have `status()` in Programmer, why was inherited `sleep()` not call this method?

Comment: When you are extending a class you cannot call a private method in a child class which you are doing in the first case. In second case as method is declared protected so you can call it in child class.

Comment: You can't override a private method, that's why the output is still: `People::status`

Comment: @AmitRay why in first case it works so?

Comment: Because the method declared under programmer is invalid as it is declared already in parent class as private. Thus in first case parent method gets executed. I recommend you to have a look at this page http://www.techflirt.com/tutorials/oop-in-php/classes-and-objects-php.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because in the first case the `Sleep` method still exists only within `People` part of the object and cannot access `Programmer::status` because it is `private` in `Programmer` part of the object, but it have another method with that name available and not overwritten, the `People::status`.

In the second case `protected` allows `Programmer::status` to overwrite `People::status`

Yes, like this it is possible for two methods of the same name to exist in one object, but each one visible only to methods from the same class definition.